# Creating c# invite for Blackberry

Tags: c#, email, invite

I need to create an email in C# that is sent to a blackberry (or outlook) and recognized as an invite. For now I create an email with inclusion of a text.ics attachment so that in outlook, the user can click on the attachment and add it to his calendar, that work. The problem is that it's not recognized as an invite in outlook invite email nor on a blackberry.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://shaunakpandit.wordpress.com/2008/09/10/sending-a-appointment-programmatically-through-code-aspnet-icalendar-format/ describes the required format at the end of the post.

Regards,
tamberg